# API Error Code 191 when adding page tabs

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I'm aware this is a very frequently asked question but I'm really new to this whole app development thing.

I am the admin of a [facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/287sqnatc) and I want to add a tab to the side of the page. So I followed facebook's instructions and created the page tab, but when I tried to access the "add to page" dialog box, I got `API Error Code 191`:

```
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

The URL I was using for the box to appear was: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=317467938291427&display=popup&next=https://www.facebook.com/287sqnatc/contact

(The contact at the end  is the URL for the app I wish to add.)

Where have I gone wrong, and can someone explain it in simple 5-year-old terms?

Comment: I have re-tagged your question (and slightly changed the markup syntax), the tags you selected were way too generic to get the right audience :o)

Answer (score 1):

`next` (or `redirect_uri`) parameter you pass to [Add Page Tab Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/) should contain either URL owned by your application or special URL `https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html`  (intended to be used in desktop applications).

You can use `FB.ui` method of JS-SDK with method `pagetab` as shown in example of [Add Page Tab Dialog documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/) this will automatically provide `redirect_uri` for dialog and allow user to add page tab without leaving your application.

Comment: That doesn't work; throws the error `This application does not support integration with your profile.`